# No System Settings App: Enable Usb debugging

Tags: android

I have android tv which does not have system settings app, I want to enable usb debugging for the tv.

I have tried several apps from play store, none of them helped (As each launch settings intent, but the tv does not have system settings app).

How can I enable USB debugging?

Comment: Most likely, you will need to ask the device manufacturer.

Comment: I have tried contacting them, but no response from them yet..